# how to make discontinuous line graph in amcharts javascript

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I use `javascript` to plot the `amcharts`, since I have so many graphs in one panel, there is no enough space to show all the balloons in one column, how to solve it?

And how to make the line graph discontinuous, I mean that if there is no value in so points, then the graph stop here, until the new point with value as the new beginning point to make the line graph?(Since if there is a long interval without values then there will be a long line crossing such interval)?

Comment: Please do some research before you ask such questions here on SO. Google will give you these links, which should answer your questions: [graph gaps](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/chart-with-gaps-in-data/), and [many balloons](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/showing-only-one-balloon-for-all-graphs/).

Comment: @gerric for the graph gap, My Date axis is not continuous(skip some date), then the graph will recognize it also as a gap, that is no what I what.

Comment: How did you manage to get your category axis skipping some dates with a date based data set? Can you provide a fiddle or at least some code? Makes such things easier.

Answer (score -2):

```
// Create series
var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series.dataFields.valueY = "value";
series.dataFields.dateX = "year";
series.strokeWidth = 3;
series.connect = false;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/

[image: Rendered graph]